# How do you label only points in ggplot that meet BOTH an X and Y cutoff?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to tell R to only label points that meet BOTH cutoffs of GSEA (-LOG10 FDR q-value) > 0.6 **AND** PSEA (-LOG10 Kuiper q-value) > 1.0 using geom_text(data=subset(df, GSEALOG > 0.6 | PSEALOG > 1.0) but it seems that this code is telling R to label points that are GSEA (-LOG10 FDR q-value) > 0.6 **OR** PSEA (-LOG10 Kuiper q-value) > 1.0. How do I tell R to label only those points that meet both cutoffs?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=PSEALOG, y=GSEALOG, color=GSEAFDRqvalue)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", na.value = NA) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=10)) +
  xlab("PSEA (-LOG10 Kuiper q-value)") + ylab("GSEA (-LOG10 FDR q-value)" ) +
  geom_text(data=subset(df, GSEALOG > 0.6 | PSEALOG > 1.0),
            aes(PSEALOG, GSEALOG, label=NAME))
```

[image]

I would also love it if the labels fell to the left of the points and didn't overlap or get cutoff by the plot margin but I'm still working on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want "both" then replace `|` with `&`, see [`?|`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html) (aka `?Logic`)

Comment: See the dupe link for more discussion about the differences between `|` and `&`. If that does not resolve your problem, please [edit] your question to make it more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) by adding the output from `dput(head(df))`, then @-ping me and we can work towards resolving the issue. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes that worked! Appreciate it :)